# how to migrate django models to new database

Tags: python, mysql, django, migrate, makemigrations

i develope a django project on my local system, and now i deployed that to a server.
i used MySql as database. whenever i try to migrate my models (using `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py makemigrations`) to server's new database, it shows me following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table '<DB_NAME>.mainapp_service' doesn't exist")
```

and doesn't create tables into the database.

i didn't move any of my local  `migration` files to server, just moved `mainapp/migrations/__init__.py` file.

how can i create all tables and run my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't run `makemigrations` on the server. You should include migrations in version control and push your migrations files to the server and then run `migrate`. Make sure you have created the database on the server and that you have it confugured in settings.py. Check out the [Workflow section on migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#workflow).

Comment: Oh i really didnt know that i should include migration files to vcs, i completely ignored them and i dont have them now! What can i do? Is there anyway to re-create migrations out of models?

Comment: Yeah. You want to make sure they're working properly before you put them on the server.